# RHEL how to sync network settings between GUI and configuration files in /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/?

Tags: networking, fedora, rhel, networkmanager

In RHEL, we can change network settings either using GUI or editing the configuration files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`.

I would like to know how the network settings (e.g. IP address, gateway, etc) in the configuration files are sync with the GUI and vice versa. Do I need to restart any service to sync the data?

1. When NetworkManager is running, do I need to turn off network service? e.g. `/etc/init.d/network stop`?
2. If I have edited the configuration files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`, and I want to sync the new configuration with the GUI, do I need to use `/etc/init.d/network restart`? If `/etc/init.d/network` has been stopped due to `#1` above, how can I sync the new configuration from text files to GUI without restarting `/etc/init.d/network`?
3. When I change network settings in the GUI, will it automatically edit the configuration files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/`? It will edit the file immediately or users need to reboot?
4. What is the relation between `NetworkManager` and `system-config-network` GUI? Is `system-config-network` GUI part of the NetworkManager package?
5. If I have stopped `/etc/init.d/network` service, can I still use the `system-config-network` GUI to configure network settings?

Thanks.

Comment: Which version of RHEL?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams RHEL 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NetworkManager use a dynamic configuration, save settings with gconf for each user, whereas network-scripts are system global configure files, you're never getting them synchronized, and you don't need to.

**When to use them?**

In most cases, if you always use, e.g dhcp on your workstation, you don't need networkmanager, just set it up in network-scripts, (and turn off NM)

But for a laptop, that may use wireless, pppoe as needed, (e.g you move around between office and home) you will need NetworkManager to be more adaptive.

Comment: Add `NM_CONTROLLED=no` to the specific `ifcfg-` script to avoid NetworkManager controlling that interface.  You can check `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` for currently-controlled interfaces.